# material elements are not loading in lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-material, lazy-loading

I am new to angular modules and lazy loading. I tried to build a lazy loading application with angular material.

The lazy loading works for me. But the material elements inside the child components are not loading

I am getting `'mat-tab' is not a known element:`

But I added MatTabModule in AppModule as like below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home/home.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './module/material/material.module';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTabsModule
    
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports:[MaterialModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My Lazy Module is like below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LazyRoutingModule } from './lazy-routing.module';
import { LazyComponent } from 'src/app/lazy/lazy/lazy.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LazyRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

This mat tab is working on HomeComponent, It is not working in lazyComponent.

I tried with stack Blitz there it is working fine, Below is the StackBlitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rpqusl

Please let me know what i am missing here ?

Comment: use shared module concept to import the MatTabsModule into your lazyComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple approach

Instead, don't import in app.module.ts, you need to import it in a module that you want, like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { LazyRoutingModule } from './lazy-routing.module';
import { LazyComponent } from 'src/app/lazy/lazy/lazy.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LazyRoutingModule,
    MatTabsModule,
  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

### Another approach

If you want to group some modules to share in your components, you can make a SharedModule:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    ~modules that you want to share~
  ],
  exports: [
    MatTabsModule,
    ~modules that you want to share~
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And now you can import in your LazyModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LazyRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```